# Data Binding Grid.Column from a custom class

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I'm new to WPF and am trying my hand at data binding, and haven't been able to find a solution to the problem that I am having. I am trying to make a window with a rectangle in it that I can dynamically switch between the left and right side of the screen, using the grid.column property. Here is my code so far, and I do not know where to go, if someone could suggest a decent website to read and solve my issue that would be nice too.

Here is my C# Code:

```
namespace WPFTestingApplication
{
    public static class GridProperties
    {
        public static int gridColumn = 1;
    }

    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

and my XAML code:

```
<Window x:Class="WPFTestingApplication.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="200" Width="400">
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Rectangle Name="Rect" Grid.Column="0" Fill="DarkGray" Margin="5" />
</Grid>
```

I want grid.column to be set to the gridColumn property in the GridProperties class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<Window x:Class="WPFTestingApplication.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPFTestingApplication"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="200" Width="400">
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Rectangle Grid.Column="{Binding Source={x:Static local:GridProperties.gridColumn}" 
               Name="Rect" Fill="DarkGray" Margin="5" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: When I try out that code Visual Studio gives me an error saying "the name GridProperties does not exist in the namespace WPFTestingApplication" and I know that it isn't a spelling error.

Comment: Edited my answer. Check the changes on *xmlns:local* declaration and see if it helps.

Comment: Is there any reason that this method should not work if i'm trying to access an element of an array, such as gridColumn[0]?